# ckEditor and drag and drop to other containers

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I need to drag and drop some elements inside ckEditor text content but also in other input element in same page with ckEditor. If in page exist ckEditor, dropping is not possible in input element (which is allowed when I remove ckEditor from page).
I discovered an eventListener over the document, for dragover created by ckEditor. If I remove this eventListener (in devtools), everything is working as I need.
It is a way to remove (disable) this eventListener by code, on ckEditor initialization or in ckEditor configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of trying to discover what happened in ckEditor, I found the problem was in the plugin simple_uploads, which prevent drop outside of ckEditor. Fortunately exists a variable config for this:

```
simpleuploads_allowDropOutside=true;
```

for disable this behaviour.